# SciChart - SCICursorModifier

Tags: scichart

For SCICursorModifier, 
1. Is there any way to activate the modifier with long press gesture instead of pan gesture?
2. Is it possible to share SCICursorModifier for multi-surface? I have tried the following code as other modifiers:

```
cursor = [[SCIMultiSurfaceModifier alloc] initWithModifierType:[MHSCICursorModifier class]];
```

and then add the modifier to the surface

```
SCICursorModifier *cursor = [m_oCursor modifierForSurface:surface];
```

However, the crosshairs only appear on one surface but not the others. Please advice.